# Array management in embedded python using boost: from python to C and viceversa

Tags: python, c++, arrays, boost

I would embed the python script inside my C++ application without to use numpy library, my issue is about array management as shown in the following code:

```
class myclass 
{
    public:


        myclass()
        {

        }

        long PrintString(char* s)
        {
            printf("%s",s);
            return 0;
        }

        long PrintBytes(char* Buffer, long size)
        {
            for(int i=0; i < size; i++)
                printf("%d", Buffer[i]);
            return 0;
        }
};


int main()
{
    try
    {
        const char* lScript =   "from ctypes import *\n"
                                "s = 'Hello world!'\n"
                                "buff = (c_char * 16)()\n"
                                "myclassobj = myclass()\n"
                                "myclassobj.PrintString(s)\n"
                                "myclassobj.PrintBytes(buff,16)\n";

        object m_MainModule; 
        object m_MainNamespace;

        Py_Initialize();
        m_MainModule = import("__main__");
        m_MainNamespace = m_MainModule.attr("__dict__");


        m_MainNamespace["myclass"] = class_<myclass>("myclass")
                                    .def("PrintString"  ,   &myclass::PrintString)
                                    .def("PrintBytes"   ,   &myclass::PrintBytes) 
                                    ;

        handle<> ignored(PyRun_String(  lScript,
                                        Py_file_input,
                                        m_MainNamespace.ptr(),
                                        m_MainNamespace.ptr()       
                                    )
                        );  
    }
    catch( error_already_set ) 
    {
        PyErr_Print();
        getchar();
    }

}
```

The string is managed correctly while the buffer array returns the following error:

> Hello world!Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line
>   6, in  Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
>       myclass.PrintBytes(myclass, c_char_Array_16, int) did not match C++ signature:
>       PrintBytes(class myclass {lvalue}, char *, long)

Please, could anyone help me for a simple solution?

My configuration

- python 2.7
- MSV C++ 2010
- boost_1_55_0
- win7